# Изменение некоторых правил русского языка по сравнению с XIX веком

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Читая произведения русской классики (в частности, Толстого и Достоевского), нахожу некоторые обороты, которые мне не совсем понятны. Хотелось бы узнать - это я не понимаю каких-то правил русского языка, которые там использованы, или какие-то правила все же устарели? Особенно это касается выделения запятыми некоторых уточнений, обстоятельственных оборотов, но не только. Есть ли какие-то правила, которые уже действительно устарели? (Про тире с запятой как единый знак уже знаю.) Привожу несколько примеров.

1. Употребление строчных букв в начале предложений (чаще вопросительных). Мне кажется, что тут имеет значение как бы связь между этими предложениями. По смыслу их можно объединить в одно целое. Но можно ли так писать сейчас?

Из "Анны Карениной":

Целый день этот Левин, разговаривая с приказчиком и мужиками и дома разговаривая с женою, с Долли, с детьми ее, с тестем, думал об одном и одном, что занимало его в это время помимо хозяйственных забот, и во всем искал отношения к своему вопросу: "Что же я такое? и где я? и зачем я здесь?"

Развитие из чего? во что? Бесконечное развитие и борьба?..

- А! вот он! - крикнул он, крепко ударив его своею большою рукой по погону.

  2. Уточнения.

Дома ей (,) за заботами о детях (,) никогда не бывало времени думать.

Он признавал, что газеты печатали много ненужного и преувеличенного (,) с одною целью - обратить на себя внимание и перекричать других.

Были и еще какие-то обстоятельственные обороты, которые вызывали вопросы, но которых сейчас не смогла найти. Можно ли привести какие-то примеры, когда обособление факультативно или когда оно вообще считается устаревшим?

Answer (score 3):

Из Розенталя:

1) Строчные буквы

Если вопросительный/восклицательный знак стоит внутри предложения между однородными членами, то следующее за знаком препинания слово, как правило, пишется со строчной буквы: Играл! проигрывал! в опеку взят указом! (Гр.).

Если слово следует за восклицательным знаком, стоящим после междометия в середине предложения, то оно пишется со строчной буквы: Но, увы! комендант ничего не мог сказать мне убедительного (Л.).

2) Уточнение

Дома ей, за заботами о детях, никогда не бывало времени думать. Оборот немного устаревший, но не обособить его нельзя, он явно не вписывается в структуру предложения и имеет обстоятельственное значение, которое следует особо выделить.

Он признавал, что газеты печатали много ненужного и преувеличенного  с однОю целью - обратить на себя внимание и перекричать других.

Здесь запятая лишняя, обстоятельство "с одною целью"  не обособляется, так как на него падает логическое ударение, далее в предложении раскрывается содержание цели.

В целом  я не вижу принципиальных изменений в правилах современной пунктуации, напротив, существует мнение,что эти правила очень стабильны, в отличие от правил орфографии.

Comment: А здесь? Вопрос Левину о венчальных свечах. - Так как же? необожженные или обожженные? вот вопрос. - Да, да! необожженные.

Comment: Нашла у Лопатина: Однако прописные буквы заменяются строчными, если перед перечислением стоят знаки двоеточие или тире (впереди имеется обобщение): Всё отвергал: законы! совесть! веру! Но: В других случаях (при отсутствии знаков двоеточия или тире перед перечислением) подобные написания со строчной буквой не соответствуют современной пунктуационной норме, например: Зачем же здесь? и в этот час? Что мне делать? просить прощения? хорошо, да в чем ?  Значит, все же это можно считать устаревшим правилом русской пунктуации.

Comment: То есть, прошу прощения, это относится к орфографии.

Answer (score 1):

Принципиальных изменений действительно нет, но всё-таки в XIX веке правила пунктуации были более демократичны. Сейчас парцеллированные конструкции принято писать с большой буквы, а два века назад они считались одним предложением.  Валгина пишет: "Примечание. Как правило, такое расчленение конструкции в прошлом не влекло за собой употребления прописных букв: Зачем же здесь? и в этот час? (Гр.); Все отвергал: законы!совесть! веру! (Гр.); Чем хуже положение мое, тем язык мой становится связаннее и холоднее. Что мне делать? просить прощения? хорошо, да в чем? (П.). У некоторых современных авторов еще можно встретить такое оформление подобных конструкций".

[Валгина Н.С.
Орфография и пунктуация](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-020.htm)

Исправлять  "неправильную" пунктуацию не следует, это веяние времени - акцентировать с помощью знаков препинания, но самим писать, конечно, нужно в соответствии с современными правилами.В поэтической речи такие вольности на каждом шагу, и они даже приветствуются, символисты пользовались этим вовсю, а Цветаева с её экспрессией - почти в каждом стихотворении "расчленяла",акцентировала,усиливала эмоции каждого слова.

В Правилах 1956 года написано:" В восклицательных предложениях знак восклицательный может ставиться после каждого однородного члена для обозначения эмоциональной прерывистости речи, например:

Пил мертвую! не спал ночей до девяти!

Всё отвергал: законы! совесть! веру!

Грибоедов

"Дома ей, за заботами о детях, никогда не бывало времени думать". -не уточнение, а пояснение, тоже существует для оправдания всяких пауз, усиления смысла отдельных частей предложения. Это вполне современное обособление.

А сейчас у нас есть такое понятие, как "авторская пунктуация",оправдывающая почти всё, кроме явного нарушения правил. Сможете объяснить, оправдать знак - ставьте, не сможете - лучше не надо. Я всё же за Чехова - коротко и ясно,  без витиеватости. А то есть товарищи, которые любят ставить знаки препинания почти после каждого слова, тольк запутывают, невозможно понять, что они хотят сказать.